# XPages mobile controls not working with iOS 8

Tags: xpages

We have a couple of simple apps that use the XPages mobile controls that no longer work on iOS 8 devices.  Tapping on outline entries, dataview entries, buttons in the header, etc. doesn't seem to do anything.  Tapping on a category to expand or collapse it in a categorized view is the only thing that seems to work.  The apps are running on a Domino 9.0 server with the openntf essentials package installed.  iOS 7 and Android devices work fine.

Anybody else having problems with the mobile controls and iOS 8?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can confirm this problem with our apps that use the mobile controls as well. It seems to be an issue with Dojo 1.8 that is used by these controls. Debug on an iPad running iOS 8 reveals "Deprecated attempt to access property 'changedTouches' on a non-TouchEvent object." and "Typerror: Attempted to assign to readonly property." in Dojo.js:7956.

UPDATE: Got it working by copying Dojo 1.9.4 to the domino\js folder.  Also had to add in the ibm and template folders into the dojo-1.9.4 folder.  These were extracted from the xsp.dojo.jar file in the Domino\osgi\shared\eclipse\plugins\com.ibm.xsp.dojo_9.0.1.20140801-1000 folder.  Then had to restart the server.  Restarting http by itself doesn't work.

Comment: 9.0.1 FP2 uses Dojo 1.9.2 http://per.lausten.dk/blog/2014/08/xpages-and-domino-9-0-1-fp2-upgrades-to-ckeditor-and-dojo.html. Not sure if that fixes the problem.

Comment: 9.0.1 FP2 does not fix the problem. It seems to require Dojo 1.9.4 or 1.10

Comment: Followed the instructions above to install Dojo 1.9.4 and that fixed the problem for me as well.  Thanks!

Comment: yep, can confirm this, apparently even with dojo 1.10.1 (why go for less? Did it on a test server running 9.0.1 FP2; didn't have time for thourough testing yet, but it's looking good); - hint: first it wouldn't want to use the version, until I realized that I had to rename the base folder from "dojo-release-1.10.1" to "dojo-1.10.1". Aaarrgggh! (it's been a long day...)

Comment: I'm worried about this solution impacting more then a single application.  This upgrades dojo for everything right?  and it's untested and unsupported by IBM.  Does it make any sense to try and install this as fake old version and then just set the .nsf to use that particular version?  Is that maybe safer overall?

Comment: The reason I elected to use 1.9.4 was because it's so close to the 1.9.2 version in Domino 9.0.1FP2.  IBM has been pretty aggressive in keeping Dojo up to date in the recent releases and we haven't had any problems...but yeah if you want to be extra cautious that's a fine idea.  Too bad all those iPhone users didn't exercise such caution in swallowing this POS release from Apple!

Comment: I agree: for a productive server I wouldn't recommend taking a jump to the next main version; moving from 1.9.2 to 1.94 should be relatively safe. Also I would recommend seeing this as a temporary workaround and keeping an eye on what IBM will be doing next. As soon as there will be an interim fix or antoher fixpack solving this by itself I would be removing htis extra installation

Comment: @DavidLeedy: As I mentioned a while ago you can change the folder for the *new* dojo version to a lower version number (everything lower then 1.5.0 is fine). When Domino is starting, it searches in the *js* folder for the highest version and will use this as the default on the whole server. A lower version prevents this. This allows you to switch the dojo version for a single application only. See here http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=323

Comment: I am really glad that I found this thread. Having the same problem on two Xpages. Wondering if it wouldn't be possible as a quick fix just to us a script block to point to the CDN for 1.10 or 1.9.4 in these two xpages, until I can install the latest version of Dojo on my server. I tried this and it seemed from looking at the source that it loaded the external file, but I still can't get touch to work. I turned aggregation off. Is there a way in the Xpage to say do not load dojo from the server, use the CDN? Or is this all a really bad idea?

Answer (score 1):

IBM has just released [9.0.1 Fix Pack 2 Interim Fix 1](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21657963) which fixes SPR PALT9P8JDG "XPage Mobile Controls Fail On iOS 8". The [technote](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21686751) has been updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

For the latest information on this issue, see this technote: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21686751

Comment: I hope someone can help me here. I have run into this same problem, and have been trying for two days to fix it. I downloaded dojo 1.9.4 and put it in the IBM/Lotus/Domino/data/domino/js folder [on a test server].There are 4 folders inside this: digit,dojo,dojox, ibm.

Comment: I don't read German but I translated Sven's page in Google and tried that but I can't get that to work either.