# Overriding Dojo version for a particular Xpages database

Tags: dojo, xpages

Apple's iOS 8 breaks certain tap functionality in versions of dojo prior to 1.9.4 (see  [Xpages mobile controls not working in iOS8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25935842/xpages-mobile-controls-not-working-with-ios-8)

The current version of Dojo in Domino 9.0.1 FP2 is 1.9.2 but that does not fix the issue. You have to use at least 1.9.4.

I have downloaded 1.9.4 and placed it in the correct folder on our test server. But I cannot get things to work. I changed the folder name of dojo 1.9.4 to 1.4.0 as I only want to use this version for 2 dbs that are having the problem.

Question 1:

What line do I put in the xsp.properties file:

xsp.client.script.dojo.version = 1.4.0
xsp.client.script.dojo.path = / domjs / dojo-1.4.0

Question 2:

There are so many things to download when I go to the dojo download page. I downloaded the zip file and used that.

When I run code to test what version of dojo I have I get 1.9.4. But when I try to load my page, I get an error.

dojo._loaders: TypeError: dojo._loaders is undefined

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You commented already on that topic here so I think you tried this one? http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=323
This is the SO thread: [XPages mobile controls not working with iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25935842/xpages-mobile-controls-not-working-with-ios-8)

Comment: Yes I commented there. My boss and I are working on this now, we downloaded the 1.9.4 dojo version just now. We are really confused about how to get the IBM folder. We must extract it from the JAR file? Can we just copy it from one of the other dojo folder?

Comment: We are getting this error in Chrome: TypeError: Cannot read property ‘unshift’ of undefined

Comment: So maybe you contact Sven directly to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

You probably have the right dojo zip, this one: http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.9.4/dojo-release-1.9.4.zip. As you say, unzip that to the `dojo-1.9.4` folder in `<server-install>\data\domino\js\`, or name the folder 1.4.0 if you want to specify it for only a few apps.

You will indeed need to copy the IBM folder from the `<server-install>\osgi\shared\eclipse\plugins\com.ibm.xsp.dojo_9.0.1.<date-stamp>\xsp.dojo.jar` into your new 1.9.4 (or 1.4.0) dojo folder. Little chance of anything working without it. Copying the ibm folder from the 1.5.2 folder is a bad idea as that is old code, and you'd certainly have issues with it working with dojo 1.9.4. In Fix Pack 2, the ibm folder from the plugin was tested/designed to work with dojo 1.9.2 (the version in that jar), so it should play fairly nice with 1.9.4.

In your XPages app, in the xsp.properties, you should only need the line:

```
xsp.client.script.dojo.version = 1.9.4
```

Rebuild your app, restart the server etc, and you should be good to go.

DISCLAIMER: This is a work-around, not a supported solution by IBM. There may be unexpected issues using this approach. It's used at your own risk.

Comment: Brian, thanks for the instructions. I was able to follow your excellent instructions. Everything in test works fine, now we will restart the production server this evening. Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: Brian, we are having one more problem. Everything worked in test, and everything worked in production, EXCEPT that the actual iOS App will not display the contents of the pages. So if I test in a browser on a PC or Mac, all is well, if I test on Safari on my iPhone it works, but in the actual app where I use a web view I see nothing. This occurs whether I am on the simulator or on my actual device. This really defeats the point of the fix. I am not doing anything really odd in the UIWebView in the app. Have you been able to use dojo mobile controls in an actual iOS app?

Comment: That's not something I've ever tried, if you mean opening an XPage within a native iOS app

Comment: Yes. We were doing this before and it worked just fine. Now it will not show anything inside the app. If this is not fixed we are going to have to abandon Xpages for mobile development. We will use the native tools in iOS and get our data via web services.

Comment: Just for further clarification, you're using your own custom built iOS application? Or are you using a hybrid container such as phonegap or cordova?

Comment: We are using a custom built iOS App, written in Objective C using Xcode. Has IBM tested this?

Comment: I'm afraid this is not a configuration that we test. If you haven't already done so, I'd recommend trying the very latest version of iOS8, 8.1 is in beta at the moment. I believe that there have been issues reported for the UIWebView in iOS8, which may be the root of your problems. Also there is a new WKWebView that you could investigate as a replacement for UIWebView. We believe your issue was caused by Apple in their upgraded OS, so would recommend investigating their support/forums for help on this. Possibly related: http://tinyurl.com/kkq34a7, http://tinyurl.com/l74fpf3

Comment: Brian, that is very helpful. I appreciate your assistance.